# How to apply a sequence of custom operations on a group by

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe of the form:

| ID | Rank | Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 3 | na | **6** |
| b | 2 | **3** | na |
| a | 1 | na | 5 |
| a | 2 | **2** | 1 |
| b | 1 | 7 | **1** |

I am trying to apply a sequence of operations:

1. Group by ID column
2. Sort by Rank Column descending
3. For each variable column, select the highest ranked non na value
   So the output would be

| ID | Var1 | Var 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2 | 6 |
| b | 3 | 1 |

So far I have

```
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% arange(desc(Rank))
```

But am unsure how to then filter each column for non NA and select the highest. The NA filter should be applied on a column basis only - if Var 1 has na, it should be excluded from the calculation of Var 1, but not for Var2.

Comment: Please share a reproducible example with the correct NA format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the first non-NA value across the selected variables after grouping:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  na_if("na") %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  arrange(desc(Rank), .by_group = T) %>% 
  summarise(across(Var1:Var2, ~ head(.x[!is.na(.x)], 1)))

# A tibble: 2 × 3
  ID    Var1  Var2 
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 a     2     6    
2 b     3     1
```

---

or with `first`:

```r
df %>% 
  na_if("na") %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(across(Var1:Var2, ~ first(.x[!is.na(.x)], order_by = "Rank")))
```

data

```r
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "ID Rank    Var1    Var2
a   3   na  6
b   2   3   na
a   1   na  5
a   2   2   1
b   1   7   1")
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
library(tidyverse)

tribble(
  ~ID, ~Rank, ~Var1, ~Var2,
  "a", 3, NA, 6,
  "b", 2, 3, NA,
  "a", 1, NA, 5,
  "a", 2, 2, 1,
  "b", 1, 7, 1
) |> 
  group_by(ID) |> 
  arrange(ID, desc(Rank)) |> 
  fill(everything(), .direction = "up") |> 
  summarise(across(starts_with("Var"), first))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   ID     Var1  Var2
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a         2     6
#> 2 b         3     1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

map(c("Var1", "Var2"), ~ 
      select(df, ID, Rank, all_of(.x)) %>% 
      group_by(ID) %>% 
      drop_na() %>% 
      slice_max(Rank) %>% 
      ungroup %>% select(-Rank)) %>% 
  reduce(inner_join)

#> Joining, by = "ID"
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   ID     Var1  Var2
#>   <chr> <int> <int>
#> 1 a         2     6
#> 2 b         3     1
```